Is it possible to connect an AWS WebSocket API to Webflow using Socket.io?
I have a WebSocket API setup with a two-way communication integration using a lambda function to host the server. When I try running my published site, I get this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://z84fa4t7k2.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OzKEsbo' from origin 'https://NAMEOFWEBSITE.webflow.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here's the code:
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');

const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://NAMEOFWEBSITE.webflow.io/",
    allowedHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
    credentials: true
  }
});

// Handle socket connections
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user connected');
  
  socket.emit("hello", "world");
});

const serverExpress = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  awsServerlessExpress.proxy(serverExpress, event, context);
};

And this is a code embed I have in Webflow:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.1.2/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io('wss://z84fa4t7k2.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ChatFunctionality/', {
      withCredentials: true,
      extraHeaders: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    });
    
    socket.on("hello", (arg) => {
        console.log(arg);
    });
  });
</script>

Excuse the messy/possibly unnecessary code, I've been trying multiple things and asking chatgpt which isn't always heplful but always confident lol.
Everyone's solution seems to be adding this:
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  }
});

But this doesn't work either, same error.
Is there a specific way I need to implement the socket with webflow?

SO AFTER READING YOUT question i have this solution hope it will work for u
app.use(function(req,res,next){
res.header("Access-control-Allow-Origin","*");
res.header("access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, X-Requested-with, content-type,Accept");
res.header("Access-controll-Allow-Methods","PUT, GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
next();
});

const io = socketIo(server,{
cors:{
Origin: "http://Name.webflow.io",
methonds: ["GET", "POST"],
allowedHeaders:["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
credential:true
}
});`


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
